# Key combinations CTRL+SHIFT+D/E/F not working

Tags: keyboard

I found that the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl-Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>/<kbd>E</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd> somtimes are not working

I really do not know what caused this, but a few tests are as follows,

- Restart the computer or logging out and back in is the only two ways I know to temporarily solve the problem, but the issue comes back after some period (no idea what triggered this);
- The hardware is OK (I think). I used the Keyboard Viewer and can see that only these three combinations have problems. Specifically, I can see that when SHIFT and CTRL are pressed, pressing D,E,or F has no response. Others are fine, for example, CTRL+SHIFT+T works fine;
- While on screen saver, the key combinations works fine while I experiment on the passwords I typed.

How can I resolve this?

PS: I recently updated to Mojave, but I recall that the issue happened once before the update. Also the model is `MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)`, and currently I'm not using an external keyboard. (I just tried plugging in another keyboard, still not working.)

Comment: Also: Do you have access to (another) external keyboard you could plug in/attach at a moment the problem occurs (this would help in figuring out whether it's a hardware or a software issue)? Can you fast-switch to an other user if the problem occurs (may need to create one beforehand) and see whether the problem occurs there as well?

Comment: @nohillside just added information on model and external keyboard. currently I do not have another account, but the combination works while I'm logging in.

Comment: Well, if it also doesn't work on the external keyboard it's most probably not a hardware issue. Any idea of some software you might have running which would capture those keystrokes?

Comment: Do the D/E/F keys work on their own?

Comment: @nohillside, I cannot think of any software that affect those keystrokes, and I'm still trying to identify what I did to cause the issue. At first I encountered the issue while using emacs, but I have been using emacs for quite some time. The issue only occurs recently.

Comment: @nohillside, yeah, D/E/F work on their own, so do Shift+d/e/f and Ctrl+d/e/f

Comment: Is Emacs always running when the problem occurs? Does it persist if you exit it then?

Comment: @nohillside, I have exited Emacs, the problem still persists. Now there is only firefox running.

Comment: @nohillside, I just found out that logging out and back in also makes the problem disappear (for a while).

Comment: @nohillside, seems I have found that `sougou pinyin` is the cause of the problem (for now). pls see update. Many Thanks!

Comment: Great. Can you please post it as an answer below (and accept it), makes it easier to find it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the problem is caused by `Sougou Pinyin`, a Chinese input software, who recently updated itself with some features along with these new shortcut keys as shown below (pls excuse the Chinise interface)
[image]
(Obviously I missed the `shift+cmd+E`).

Now I have disabled them all.